# Hide watermark for wholesalers

Tags: magento-1.9, image

I want to add a watermark to my images in the store. But when a dealer is logged in, he must see the original images. The dealer are in the customer group Dealers.

Is it possible to hide the watermark for the dealers / a customer group?

I have been searching for this, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are wholesalers a specific store, or customer group. how are they identified by the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The water mark is set in the method `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init` by these lines:

```
    $this->setWatermark(
        Mage::getStoreConfig("design/watermark/{$this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()}_image")
    );
    $this->setWatermarkImageOpacity(
        Mage::getStoreConfig("design/watermark/{$this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()}_imageOpacity")
    );
    $this->setWatermarkPosition(
        Mage::getStoreConfig("design/watermark/{$this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()}_position")
    );
    $this->setWatermarkSize(
        Mage::getStoreConfig("design/watermark/{$this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()}_size")
    );
```

You can try to rewrite this method and wrap the code above in an if statement that checks if the current user belongs to a certain group.
Something like this:

```
$dealerCustomerGroupIds = array(9, 10);
if (!in_array(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),  $dealerCustomerGroupIds)) {
    //the code from above goes here
}
```

Of course this is a quick and dirty way of doing it. It would be cleaner to have a field in the system->configuration from where you can select the user groups that should not see watermarks. Then read that setting and populate the `$dealerCustomerGroupIds` variable. I just added the code here as a proof of concept.

Comment: Where can I find this method Marius?

Comment: I stated in the answer. Class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`. If you want the file is `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php`. But please don't edit the core. Rewrite the class. Here is a [tutorial on how to do that](http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/)

Comment: Thanks! It works. There is one small error in the code. The arrayname where you declare the array and in the if aren't the same. If they are both $dealerCustomerGroupIds it works fine!

Comment: @RobinV91NL. Sorry for that. I didn't test the code. I will fix it immediately.